# object "nn" not found in predict function in R Caret package

Tags: r, r-caret

When i run the predict function in the code below after building an ensemble model of four algorithms and then trying to use the ensemble model to make prediction on new data, i get the error that: object "nn" not found

```
     models2 <- caretList(
     log_sales~., data=train.data.final,
     trControl=trnCtrl,  tuneList=list(
     rf=caretModelSpec(method="rf", tuneGrid=expand.grid(.mtry=c(1:8)) ),  
     nn=caretModelSpec(method="nnet", tuneGrid=expand.grid(.decay = 
     c(0,0.001,0.01, 0.1, 0.5), .size = c(5:10)), preProcess=c("center", 
     "scale"),linout=TRUE, trace=FALSE, maxit = 1000),
     gbm=caretModelSpec(method="gbm", 
     tuneGrid=expand.grid(interaction.depth = seq(1, 7, by = 2), n.trees = 
     seq(100, 1000, by = 50),shrinkage = c(0.01,0.1), n.minobsinnode = 10) 
     ),
     xgb=caretModelSpec(method="xgbTree", tuneGrid=expand.grid(nrounds = 
     1000,eta = c(0.01,0.05, 0.07, 0.1), max_depth = c(4:14), gamma=0, 
     colsample_bytree = c(0.75), subsample = c(0.50), min_child_weight =0 ) )

  )
  )

  stack.glm <- caretStack(models2, method="glm",  trControl=trnCtrl)
  stack.pred <- predict(stack.glm, newdata = testing)
```

Error in eval(predvars, data, env) : object 'nn' not found

Comment: Can you please provide a minimal reprex (reproducible example)? The goal of a reprex is to make it as easy as possible for me to recreate your problem so that I can fix it: please help me help you!

If you've never heard of a reprex before, start by reading "[What is a reprex](https://github.com/tidyverse/reprex#what-is-a-reprex)", and follow the advice further down that page.

Comment: I don't know why, but you should call the models the same as they are called in `caret`. for example you should use `tuneList = list(rf = ..., nnet = ..., gbm = ..., xgbTree = ....)`. I probably read it in the documentation